# How can i get current year in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my Excel sheet I used like "12/06/2009".

But when in my selenium webdriver I am always getting 12/06/09.
How  can i get the original format i used in excel

How can i get current year in selenium webdriver?

Comment: Provide the code you've written first.

Comment: I dont think getting the date or year has anything to do with selenium. It is based on the programming language you use.

Comment: I used in Selenium like this System.out.println(s.getCell(0,i).getContents()); but iam getting "12/06/09" instead of "12/06/2009".Anybody can help me

Comment: @namitha: did you got what you want?

Answer (score 4):

For fetching the date in desired format you can use following:

```
SimpleDateFormat DtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date=Test.getRow(RowNum).getCell(CellNum).getDateCellValue();
System.out.println(DtFormat.format(date).toString());
```

And now if the cell value is 12/06/2009, it will give o/p as 12/06/2009.

For date format you need to define the format as following:

```
SimpleDateFormat DtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(DtFormat.format(date).toString());
```

The output will be the current date & Time like "Tue 11-06-2013 08:40:30 PM"

So as per your requirement, you can remove the unwanted fields from the DtFormat.